# Execute reader connection error

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MJ-PC;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True ");
        con.Open();
    }

    protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select password from TestDemo where userName'" + txtusername .Text+ "'", con);

        //cmd.Connection = con;

        SqlDataReader da;
        da = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (!da.Read())
        {
            Response.Write("Wrong Details");
        }
        else
        {
            if(da[0].ToString()==txtusername.Text)
                 Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx");
            else
                Response.Write("Wrong Password");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where's the error? At con.Open() or cmd.ExecuteReader()?

Answer (score 1):

`where username **=**`
forgot equality sign

Also, the conenction you open and the connection you use are different

Comment: Heh, good catch. But still gotta figure out where he got an error. It could be a typo here.

Comment: does con.open() work fine? Also, assign resulting query to a string , debug, copy it tobuffer and run directly on sql via sql studio

Comment: Nah, I am very sure it won't work fine. See my answer for 'why'

Comment: Not sure i underatsnd you. Anyway, to build a proper connection string use VS integrated datasource wizard - just build it and test until it works. To make correct query try it on direct sql (like SSMS). If both work then do: 1) create and open connection 2) run query on it. Obviuosly :))

Comment: Well, if you see, he is trying to use `con` object in `btnsubmit_Click` handler, but according to C# rules, you CANNOT access a local object defined in one method, and use it in another method

Comment: Arr, i'm confused, thouthg you are the author :)) I didnt talk about con and scope at all :) You're, right he needs proper var declaration.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40411/discussion-between-aniket-and-jim)

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, you open a connection to the SQL server in `Page_Load` handler. But you don't close it.

If you try to open another one, or try to execute on a closed `SqlConnection` object, you might get an error.

A good way to do this is do something like this:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
{        
  try    
   {
            connection.Open();
          //do something here

   } 
   catch (Exception) 
   { 
      /*Handle error*/ 
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     SqlConnection con;    
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
    try
    {            
    con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MJ-PC;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True");
                con.Open();
    }
    catch
    {
    //Handles exceptions here
    }
            }

            protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
              try
              {
                //SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select password from TestDemo where userName='" + txtusername .Text+ "'", con);

                //cmd.Connection = con;

                SqlDataReader da;
                da = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (!da.Read())
                {
                    Response.Write("Wrong Details");
                }
                else
                {
                    if(da[0].ToString()==txtusername.Text)
                         Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx");
                    else
                        Response.Write("Wrong Password");
                }
              }
              finally
              {
              con.Close();
              }
            }
```

Comment: How do you reference `con` object in `btnsubmit_Click()`?

Comment: @Ankit : Please check it now.

Comment: If it were upto me, I would give it another -1, you do OPEN the connection, but you don't close it. When you will try to open it again ever in the future, you will get a yellow-red screen of death on asp.net

Answer (score 0):

If you code for login, then here a neat version code, Depend on your flagset you can redirect or display wrong password msg

```
    bool flagset=false;
    SqlDataReader dr;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cn.ConnectionString))
    {
     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
       {
        cmd.CommandText = "select password from TestDemo where userName=@uName";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uName", txtusername.Text); 
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
         if (dr.HasRows){
           while (dr.Read())
            {
                if(dr[0].ToString()==txtusername.Text)
                 {     flagset=true;   }
            }
            }dr.Close();
             con.Close();
      }
}return flagset;
```